# execute a .sql file using Excel vba where (.sql) query contains joins from Linked Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to run a .SQL Query from C: Drive using Excel VBA macro. The code below does not work for Linked Server

From the code Final.sql below: LATESTDUMP and OLDDUMP Are linkedServer

**Final.sql** Code

```
 INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 
8.0;Database=C:\Queries\Results\DumpQuery.xlsx;','SELECT * FROM  [Table1$]') 
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  *
    FROM LATESTDUMP...Table1) t1

FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM OLDDUMP...Table1) t2

ON t1.id = t2.id

WHERE
    t1.id IS NULL OR
    t2.id IS NULL
```

VBA Code to execute Final.sql

```
Sub Sqlquery()
Dim Cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Rst As New ADODB.recordSet
Dim ConnectionString, SqlTextFile, SqlStatement As String

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 'Connection to SQl Server
ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
"Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
"Data Source=MOLP0533183"

Cnn.Open ConnectionString
Cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = ""

Dim hnd As Integer
hnd = FreeFile

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Open "C:\Queries\Final.sql" For Input As hnd

Dim row As String
Do Until EOF(hnd)
    Line Input #hnd, row
    strSQL = strSQL & row & vbNewLine


Loop

Close #hnd

Debug.Print strSQL

Rst.Open strSQL, Cnn

End Sub
```

The VBA Code is getting executed without errors but i am not getting any output in DumpQuery.xlsx

Comment: Could it be because OLDDUMP and NEWDUMP contain identical data (`t1.id = t2.id`)? You also have a typo in sql command qith the extra OR at the end.

Comment: @ Alex... The Data is slightly different on OLDDUMP and NEWDUMP. I removed the extra OR. I think the error has some thing to do with Linked Servers. I tried the code with local Databases and it works perfectly fine.I changed the code a little and i am getting the error " The OLE DB provider  " Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server LATESTDUMP reported an error"

Comment: just run the query from SSMS on the same server as where excel runs it and see what results you get.

Comment: Works perfectly fine with SSMS but not with vba